# find text from visible HTML in python

Tags: python, html

i'm trying to do the following:

1. i have a text file that have some values line by line.
2. a website that generate list of values based on the page number. the values are XXX & YYY in the example below.
3. python script reads the first text file (efficient 0(1) lookups using a set) and search in the website page after page by +1, and if a value match found it must print the page number.

the search must be like www.site.com/1 www.site.com/2 www.site.com/3 ...etc

HTML source:

```
<pre class="values">
    <strong>A</strong>
    <strong>B</strong>
    <strong>C</strong>
    <span id="1">
        <a href="/#">+</a> 
        <span title="1">1</span>
        <a href="/#">XXX</a>
        <a href="/#">YYY</a>
    </span>
</pre>
```

text file efficient 0(1) lookups using a set:

```
with open("values.txt", "r") as f1:
        lines = set(f1) # efficient 0(1) lookups using a set
        for line in HTML :
            if line in lines:
                print(line)
```

Comment: What is your desired output for the provided HTML source?

Comment: the output that i want is XXX and YYY if any matched whats in the .txt file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

<pre class="values">
    <strong>A</strong>
    <strong>B</strong>
    <strong>C</strong>
    <span id="1">
        <a href="/#">+</a> 
        <span title="1">1</span>
        <a href="/#">XXX</a> <a href="/#">YYY</a>
    </span>
</pre>

with open('/path/to/file.html') as fp:
    html = ET.fromstring(fp.read())

for node in html.iter():
    if node.tag == 'a':
        print node.text
```

Comment: can you explain more please. maybe some code that i can hack.

Comment: the html code must not be added to the python code. python code must request (parse) the webpages and search if any line from the .txt file match anything on the webpage.

Comment: Well, here is some code for you to hack as you ask. Happy Hacking!